# MEAN stack app stops working if any collection has more than 100 documents

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got an app running with the following versions

- angularjs 1.46
- mongo 4.0.0
- mongoose 4.1.12
- express 4.7.4
- node 8.11.3

All works great as long as all my tables have 100 or less documents. As soon as I get to 101 it stops returning any documents. These are small docs with only a single index, so size isn't an issue. I'm thinking that there is a setting somewhere that I can't find which is causing this, but this is my first time using these technologies. This behavior happens both locally (on windows box) and when deployed on an AWS unix box (code transferred through git).

I've simplified it to this. I've defined a simple model and route to try to isolate the issue. So I just put the route in the browser which I think takes angular out of the equation. Up to 100 docs and the data is returned in the browser. 101 docs and no response, but there is an error on the get call (see below). In developer tools when I look at network>xhr it says it's stalledor pending for minutes before the error finally comes back. In addCtrl.js the log statement is not reached. So it's stalling somewhere in the GET call, I just don't know why 101 is a magic roadblock.

If I manually return the records (paste the json directly into the return from the route) it works fine. So it appears to be something in the mongo/mongoose/node end (at least I think that's what it means).

In looking at where it stops running it appears to be line 10695 in the angular.js file which reads

```
xhr.send(isUndefined(post) ? null : post);
```

for a failed run it ends like this

[image]

for a successful run it looks like this

[image]

Here is the error reported by the get call in routes

> angular.js:10695 GET http://localhost:3000/censusBlocks/ 0 ()
>   (anonymous) @ angular.js:10695 sendReq @ angular.js:10514
>   serverRequest @ angular.js:10221 processQueue @ angular.js:14678
>   (anonymous) @ angular.js:14694 $eval @ angular.js:15922 $digest @
>   angular.js:15733 $apply @ angular.js:16030 bootstrapApply @
>   angular.js:1660 invoke @ angular.js:4476 doBootstrap @ angular.js:1658
>   bootstrap @ angular.js:1678 angularInit @ angular.js:1572 (anonymous)
>   @ angular.js:28821 trigger @ angular.js:3022 eventHandler @
>   angular.js:3296

The only thing different between the runs is the number of documents. I really can't figure this out.

I did discover than if I use `var query = CensusBlock.find({}).limit(itemcount);`  and set item count to 101, then it will return 101 and work fine. But if I set the limit to 102, it stops working again. Or if I increase the document count to 102 it also stops working again.

I also tried using Mongo version 3.6.6 and got the same behavior. I also just tried on a fresh computer using npm install (I manually copied the angular.js file) and the problem persists. I know others aren't able to replicate, but I can't get it to stop. So I am truly baffled and frustrated.

Here's the code, which is pretty straightforward, so I feel like this must be some odd setting somewhere, I just can't figure out where.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "TEst",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "gina",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.7.2",
    "mongoose": "~4.1.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.5.2"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
// Dependencies
// -----------------------------------------------------
var express         = require('express');
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var port            = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');

var app = express();


// Express Configuration
// -----------------------------------------------------
// Sets the connection to MongoDB
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test");

// Logging and Parsing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                 // sets the static files location to public
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components')); // Use BowerComponents
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));               // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.text());                                     // allows bodyParser to look at raw text
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json'}));  // parse application/vnd.api+json as json

// Routes
// ------------------------------------------------------
require('./app/routes.js')(app);


// Listen
// -------------------------------------------------------
app.listen(port);
console.log('App listening on port ' + port);
```

routes.js. Note there is no .limit on the query, it's just trying to get all the docs. As noted above, adding .limit(101) seems to make it work, but then it would have to get the document each time before making the call. Manually putting the records in here eliminates the issue.

```
// Dependencies
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var CensusBlock     = require('./model.js');

// Opens App Routes
module.exports = function(app) {

    // GET Routes
    // --------------------------------------------------------
    // Retrieve the censuslocks from the db
    app.get('/censusBlocks', function (req, res) {
        var blocklist = new CensusBlock(req.body);
        console.log('in route censusblocks'); //This reports
        var query = CensusBlock.find({});
        //var query = CensusBlock.find({}).limit(itemcount); //This seems to work if itemcount is less than or equal to the document count
        query.exec(function (err, blocklist) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(`Error: ${err}`); 
                res.send(err);
            }
            // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of all sites
            console.log('in route censusblocks query return'); //This does not report for 101
            res.json(blocklist);

            //Manually returning the data here (as shown below) works so it's the get that's failing somehow
            //return res.json([{}…]);
        });
    });
};
```

app.js

```
// Declares the initial angular module "meanApp". Module grabs other controllers and services.
var app = angular.module('meanApp', ['addCtrl']);
```

addCtrl.js

```
// Creates the addCtrl Module and Controller.
// var addCtrl = angular.module('addCtrl', ['$scope', '$http']); //causes compile error as noted in comments
var addCtrl = angular.module('addCtrl', []);
addCtrl.controller('addCtrl', function($scope, $http){

    // Initializes Variables
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $scope.formData = {};

    // Functions
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $http.get('/censusBlocks/').success(function (response) {
        console.log('There are ' + response.length + ' censusblocks'); //This does not report for 101 docs
        $scope.blocks = response;
    }).error(function () { });
});
```

model.js

```
// Pulls Mongoose dependency for creating schemas
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;

var CensusBlockSchema = new Schema({
    geoid10: Number,
    intptlat10: Number,
    intptlon10: Number,
    blockarea: Number
});

CensusBlockSchema.index({ geoid10: 1 }, { unique: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('censusblocks', CensusBlockSchema);
```

config.js

```
// Sets the MongoDB Database options
module.exports = {

    local:
    {
        name: "testapp",
        url: "mongodb://localhost/test",
        port: 27017
    }
};
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>

<html class="no-js" ng-app="meanApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Scotch MEAN Map</title>
    <meta name="description" content="test App">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- JS Source -->
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
     <!-- Angular Scripts -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/addCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="addCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="census block">Pick the Census Block</label>
            <select label="census block" ng-model="formdata.selectedBlock"  ng-options="x.geoid10 for x in blocks | orderBy:'geoid10' "></select>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You said you did this without the Angular part to test?  I just tried exactly your code and same DB versions and everything, no issue.  Got 150 records back in the blink of an eye.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but in your `get` route, if you get an error, I'm pretty sure you should use `return res.send(err)` or even better would be `res.send(err); return next(err);` to send the error to express. I'm wondering if you are getting an error and something is going wrong at `res.json(blocklist)` and it's silently failing. Also, try doing the same query in a mongo shell to see if you get an error (isolating the issue just to mongo).

Comment: @Paul I definitely have the angular part. I was just doing a call in the browser window directly to try to isolate the problem.

Comment: @JosephSerido Last night while investigating I did run the query in mongo shell and it returns fine. I updated the route with the your second suggestion, but don't see any difference.in behavior.

Comment: @gina what if you changed `if (err) res.send(err);` to `if (err) { console.log(\`Error: ${err}\`); res.send(err); }`. Does it log anything at all?

Comment: @JosephSerido I added the error log and it did log an error which I added into the question above. But it was not meaningful to me other than it stops on angular.js 10695 which is the xhr send line.

Comment: Well, it's also interesting to me that on a successful run you're getting a 304 rather than a 200.  That implies that it's pulling from the browser cache rather than hitting the server.  Try clearing the cache and querying again with < 100 docs and see if you still don't have an error.

Comment: Also, please update your code since it sounds like you've added some error handling that wasn't in the original example.

Comment: I cleared the cache and got 200. I think it was only using the cache because I keep rerunning in the good and bad state. The code has been updated to reflect the new console logging..

Comment: @gina that error is from angular specifically, but what does node.js say? That should be a different log. Also, if you think about it, you're sending back two responses when it has an error. Once for the `res.send(err)` and another for `res.json(blocklist)` which I assume `blocklist` would be `undefined` and cause another issue.

Comment: @JosephSerido I'm not sure where to find the node.js log. In the commande window where I start the app, no error shows up.

Comment: @gina If you're running `node index.js` or something similar in the command prompt, then the log should show up in there. I'd recommend putting a log before your `if` statement to make sure you are at least getting to the callback.

Comment: @gina one more thing, try taking your GET endpoint and manually returning the 101 documents back to the caller, taking out the MongoDB call.

Comment: @JosephSerido I'm not sure how to execute your last comment about manually returning the 101 docs.

Comment: @gina in the routes.js file, for the `get('censusBlocks', ...)` instead of doing `query.exec(...)` just do `return res.json([{...}, ...]);` where you copy and paste in the 101 documents into your code. If you do this then run the route and it works as expected with no errors, then something's up with contacting mongo through node. I'm not sure what that would be, but at least it would isolate the problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: @JosephSerido Thanks for the instructions. When I paste in the json (even lots more than 100) it works great.

Comment: Does it make any difference that I'm connecting to a mongo instance that lives on the same box as the application? I'm trying to figure out how to connect it to a service running elsewhere to eliminate that as an issue.

Comment: @JosephSerido Thanks for the manual test. It got me to focus on mongoose which led to finding an version incompatibility issue.

Comment: @gina awesome! I'm glad you were able to figure it out in the end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a version incompatibility issue. I updated mongoose to 5.2.9 and now it works.

The mongoose page which lists compatibility is https://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html

It says (in case the link breaks)

> MongoDB Server 4.0.x: mongoose ^5.2.0

Comment: If possible, could you please link to an article / post about how you found out about the incompatibility issue? I'm curious to know where you found the solution.

Comment: @JosephSerido I added the link.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, sorry for not noticing this before, but you failed to inject your dependencies into your module.

The controller needs $scope and $http so you should declare them:

```
var addCtrl = angular.module('addCtrl', ['$scope', '$http']);
```

Comment: +1 because this should be in there, but I don't see how this explains how the OP's app would work with 100 docs, but not 101.

Comment: Yeah, I haven’t been able to replicate that part.

Comment: When I add that in I get a compile error: `var addCtrl = angular.module('addCtrl', ['$scope', '$http']);` yields the error: [$injector:nomod] Module '$scope' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.